# Maven-NetBeans default paths on Windows 7?

Tags: maven, netbeans, windows-7

I'm trying to understand some details about NetBeans interaction with its included Maven, specifically how NB knows where "Bundled" maven is, and how maven knows where its local repository is -- ie: in what config files are these captured.

This is a default install of current NetBeans (32 bit) 7.2 on Win7. The install did not set M2_HOME environment variable, nor any entry in PATH.

### "Bundled" maven location

- NetBeans Tools > Options > Java > Maven Home is set to "Bundled" -- I'm guessing somewhere the word "Bundled" maps to some path... where is that mapping? (grep didn't turn up anything.)
- When NetBeans runs Maven, I see output window info that to my surprise says that it doesn't run the maven installation that's at C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2\java\maven, instead it runs the complete copy of maven at C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\maven (\bin\mvn.bat).

So evidently that's what "Bundled" points to -- but why this duplicate maven file tree when there's already one included under NB's tree under Program Files?

(And FWIW, if M2_HOME has not been set, mvn.bat sets M2_HOME to mvn.bat's parent dir, so  M2_HOME itself is explained, but not how NB decided that "Bundled" = that path to mvn.bat.)

### Maven's repo location

- I see the Maven local repository is at C:\Users[user].m2 as expected, but again, where is this specified?

I resist believing that Bundled and repo paths are hardcoded, so I'm assuming there's some config files somewhere that capture these paths, and I'd like to know where it is!

BTW, I do realize that the repo path can be overridden in maven\conf\settings.xml -- currently that's got only comments, so not influencing anything.

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using NetBeans 7.2.1

It required a little bit hacking, but:

1. Shutdown NetBeans application
2. Go to   %AppData%\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\maven\repositories
3. There should be two files: central.properties and local.properties Add several lines to local.properties:

===

```
local=D:/repo/
localRepositoryPath=D:/repo/
localRepository=D:/repo/
localPath=D:/repo/
path=D:/repo/
```

I'm sure that at least one entry should be correct xD. NetBeans ignores incorrect entries.
Althrough it disappears after reindexing but NetBeans remembers it somehow anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The embedded maven in NB is sometimes difficult to control and other time doesn't work at all.
I recommande you to install maven at your own.

http://maven.apache.org/download.html

After the installation just go NB and tell it where the new Maven is installed.

I see the Maven local repository is at C:\Users[user].m2 as expected, but again, where is this specified?

This is a default settings. for more information just take time a read here [maven by example](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment, but I'm not perceiving an answer in there. Specifically:

Comment: (Grr -- 5-min edit rule.)
Thanks for commenting, but I'm not seeing an answer in there. Specifically:  (1) Where in NB's files is the mapping of Bundled to path specified and (2) where in Maven's files is the default local repo path specified (or should I interpret your answer as a belief that it's hardcoded?)  

That said, you've raised the interesting issue of bundled maven being difficult to control -- what do you mean? Does NB not run Maven when it should? Or do you mean that it's difficult to run bundled maven from the command line? Or that bundled maven is somehow broken?  -- thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The default path for NetBeans maven is explained in:
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3.1\java\maven\conf\settings.xml

```
<!-- localRepository
| The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
|
| Default: ~/.m2/repository
<localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>     
-->
```

On windows "~/" is C:\Users\[Username]

Thus the default bundled path is:
C:\Users\[Username]\.m2\repository

Comment: Thanks for the comment on the second part of the question.  In the first part of the question I noted that Netbeans was running the copy of maven located at: C:\Users\ [user]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\maven (\bin\mvn.bat).  Paralleling your answer, that installation also has a \conf\settings.xml, with the same comment. Answering the second part of the question.
But what about the first part -- how does "Bundled" map to the copy of maven at C:\Users\ [user]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\maven (\bin\mvn.bat)?